# defaultdict lambda with two arguments (it's not argument per se for lack of word)

Tags: python

Hi I'm new to python defaultdict and it's callable argument. I have the following mocked code. Can someone help me to understand it?

```
a = 1.0
d = defaultdict(
        lambda: a,
        [(w, i) for w, i in dict_foo.items()])
```

What would d look like if d[key] when the key doesn't exist?

Comment: The lambda is only the first line, the second are the items to "load" into the `defaultdict`.

Comment: Where did you find that code?

Comment: The list comprehension seems pointless; using `dict_foo` directly would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "if d[key] when the key doesn't exist"?

Comment: I simplified the code when I posted the question. The list comprehension actually is like this: [(w, func(i)) for w, i in dict_foo.items()]

Answer (score 3):

The part after the comma (`,`) is *not* part of the lambda-expression, these are elements that are treated like these would as if you had constructed a `dict`. Like described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

> Returns a new dictionary-like object. defaultdict is a subclass of the
>   built-in dict class. It overrides one method and adds one writable
>   instance variable. **The remaining functionality is the same as for
>   the `dict` class** and is not documented here.

Now a `dict` can take as parameter an iterable of 2-tuples, and it then will add these as key-value pairs.

So the above is, more or less, equivalent to:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: a)
for w, i in dict_foo.items():
    d[w] = i
```

Given `dict_foo` is a dictionary, it is probably more elegant to write:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: a, dict_foo)
```

We here thus construct a `defaultdict` with as key-value pairs the items in `dict_foo`, and we use `lambda: a` as a "factory" to construct values for missing keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I finally got it! Thanks a million!