# Nested `defaultdict of defaultdict of defaultdict` each with a backreference

Tags: python, trie, defaultdict, recursive-datastructures

Using `tree = lambda: dedfaultdict(tree)`, I can replace the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

END = '$'
words = ['hi', 'hello', 'hiya', 'hey']

root = {}
for word in words:
  node = root
  for ch in word:
    node = node.setdefault(ch, {}) # <---- Code that can be replaced
  node[END] = None
```

with:

```
from collections import defaultdict

END = '$'
words = ['hi', 'hello', 'hiya', 'hey']

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
root = tree()
for word in words:
  node = root
  for ch in word:
    node = node[ch] # <------ Replaced code
  node[END] = None
```

---

What I actually want is for each dictionary node to have a backreference to its parent dictionary node. I can do this as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

BACKREF, END = 'BACKREF', '$'
words = ['hi', 'hello', 'hiya', 'hey']

root = {}
for word in words:
  node = root
  for ch in word:
    node = node.setdefault(ch, {BACKREF: node}) # <---- Code I want to replace
  node[END] = None
```

*(proof that this works: [link](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=from%20collections%20import%20defaultdict%0A%0ABACKREF,%20END%20%3D%20%27backref%27,%20%27%24%27%0A%0Atree%20%3D%20lambda%3A%20defaultdict%28tree%29%0Aroot%20%3D%20tree%28%29%0Aroot%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%20None%0A%0Awords%20%3D%20%5B%27hi%27,%20%27hello%27,%20%27hiya%27,%20%27hey%27%5D%0Afor%20word%20in%20words%3A%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%3D%20root%0A%20%20%20%20for%20c%20in%20word%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Alt%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%3D%20node.setdefault%28c,%20%7BBACKREF%3A%20node%7D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20%23%20Alt%202%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20node%5Bc%5D%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%20node%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20node%20%3D%20node%5Bc%5D%0A%20%20%20%20node%5BEND%5D%20%3D%20None%0A%0A%23%20---%0A%0Aassert%20root%5BBACKREF%5D%20is%20None%0Afor%20word%20in%20words%3A%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%3D%20root%0A%20%20%20%20for%20c%20in%20word%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20assert%20c%20in%20node%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20assert%20node%5Bc%5D%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%3D%20node%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%3D%20node%5Bc%5D%0A%20%20%20%20assert%20END%20in%20node%0A%0A%23%20---%0A%0Aassert%20root%5BBACKREF%5D%20is%20None%0Aassert%20set%28root.keys%28%29%29%20%3D%3D%20%7BBACKREF,%20%27h%27%7D%0A%0Ah%20%3D%20root%5B%27h%27%5D%0Aassert%20h%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%3D%20root%0Aassert%20set%28h.keys%28%29%29%20%3D%3D%20%7BBACKREF,%20%27e%27,%20%27i%27%7D%0A%0Ahe%20%3D%20h%5B%27e%27%5D%0Aassert%20he%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%3D%20h%0Aassert%20set%28he.keys%28%29%29%20%3D%3D%20%7BBACKREF,%20%27l%27,%20%27y%27%7D%0A%0Ahel%20%3D%20he%5B%27l%27%5D%0Aassert%20hel%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%3D%20he%0Aassert%20set%28hel.keys%28%29%29%20%3D%3D%20%7BBACKREF,%20%27l%27%7D%0A%0Ahell%20%3D%20hel%5B%27l%27%5D%0Aassert%20hell%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%3D%20hel%0Aassert%20set%28hell.keys%28%29%29%20%3D%3D%20%7BBACKREF,%20%27o%27%7D%0A%0Ahello%20%3D%20hell%5B%27o%27%5D%0Aassert%20hello%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%3D%20hell%0Aassert%20set%28hello.keys%28%29%29%20%3D%3D%20%7BBACKREF,%20END%7D%0Aassert%20hello%5BEND%5D%20is%20None%0A%0Ahey%20%3D%20he%5B%27y%27%5D%0Aassert%20hey%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%3D%20he%0Aassert%20set%28hey.keys%28%29%29%20%3D%3D%20%7BBACKREF,%20END%7D%0Aassert%20hey%5BEND%5D%20is%20None%0A%0Ahi%20%3D%20h%5B%27i%27%5D%0Aassert%20hi%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%3D%20h%0Aassert%20set%28hi.keys%28%29%29%20%3D%3D%20%7BBACKREF,%20END,%20%27y%27%7D%0Aassert%20hi%5BEND%5D%20is%20None%0A%0Ahiy%20%3D%20hi%5B%27y%27%5D%0Aassert%20hiy%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%3D%20hi%0Aassert%20set%28hiy.keys%28%29%29%20%3D%3D%20%7BBACKREF,%20%27a%27%7D%0A%0Ahiya%20%3D%20hiy%5B%27a%27%5D%0Aassert%20hiya%5BBACKREF%5D%20%3D%3D%20hiy%0Aassert%20set%28hiya.keys%28%29%29%20%3D%3D%20%7BBACKREF,%20END%7D%0Aassert%20hiya%5BEND%5D%20is%20None&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false))*

So, given that I was able to use `tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)` to replace

- `node = node.setdefault(ch, {})`
- with `node = node[ch]`

is there a way I can use a modified version of `tree = lambda: default(tree)` to replace

- `node = node.setdefault(ch, {BACKREF: node})`
- with something simpler, such as perhaps `node = node[ch]`
  ?

---

I have tried something like:

```
def tree():
  _ = defaultdict(tree)
  _[BACKREF] = ?
  return _
root = tree()
h = root['h']
```

But that would require `tree` to know which dictionary invoked the call to `tree`. E.g. in `h = root['h']`, `root['h']` invokes a call to `tree` because `h` is not yet in `root`. `tree` would have to know it was invoked via the call `root['h']` so that it could do `h[BACKREF] = root`. Is there a way around this? Is it a bad idea even if it can be done?

I know the backreferences technically means that the trie will have cycles (and not be truly a tree), but the way I plan to traverse the trie, this won't be an issue. The reason I want backreferences is because it will be useful if I want to delete a word from the trie. For example, say I have the following trie:

[image: Trie]

and that I am at `root['h']['e']['l']['l']['o']` and want to delete `'hello'` from the trie. I can do this by backtracking up the trie from `root['h']['e']['l']['l']['o']` to `root['h']['e']['l']['l']` to `root['h']['e']['l']` to `root['h']['e']` (I stop here because `len(set(root['h']['e'].keys()) - {BACKREF}) > 1`. Then I can simply do `del root['h']['e']['l']` and I will have cleaved off the `'llo$'` from `'he'` meaning the trie will still have `'hey'`. Although there are alternatives, backtracking up the trie will be very easy with the backreferences.

---

###### Context on `tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)`

Using:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
root = tree()
```

one can create arbitrarily nested `dict`s. E.g. after:

```
root['h']['i']
root['h']['e']['l']['l']['o']
root['h']['i']['y']['a']
root['h']['e']['y']
```

`root` will look like:

```
{'h': {'i': {'y': {'a': {}}}, 'e': {'y': {}, 'l': {'l': {'o': {}}}}}}
```

This represents a tree that looks like this:
[image: Trie]
*visualized using [https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Trie.html](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/Trie.html)*

Comment: Give the same `{BACKREF: node}` to `defaultdict`?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I'm not sure how to put `{BACKREF: node}` into `tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)` or something similar. Another issue is that `node` is not defined at the time `tree` is defined - how do I get around that?

Comment: If I do `root = defaultdict(lambda: {BACKREF: root})` that works for one nesting level, but not further - e.g. `root['h']` would be result in `root = {'h': {'backref': root}}` as desired, but if I try to go further with `root['h']['i']` that causes a `KeyErrror: 'i'` since `root['h']` is just a regular `dict` and is not itself a `defaultdict(lambda: {BACKREF: root['h']})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Solution 1

Giving the same `{BACKREF: node}` to `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

BACKREF, END = 'BACKREF', '$'
words = ['hi', 'hello', 'hiya', 'hey']

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree, {BACKREF: node})
node = None
root = tree()
for word in words:
  node = root
  for ch in word:
    node = node[ch]
  node[END] = None
```

The `root` node has a backref `None`, can be deleted if bothersome.

##### Solution 2

The above works fine if that code is the only code that creates tree nodes (seems likely to me, judging by the times I've built such trees myself). Otherwise you'd need to ensure that `node` points to the correct parent node. If that's an issue, here's an alternative with a dict (not defaultdict) subclass that implements [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__missing__#object.__missing__) to automatically create children with backrefs when needed:

```
BACKREF, END = 'BACKREF', '$'
words = ['hi', 'hello', 'hiya', 'hey']

class Tree(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        child = self[key] = Tree({BACKREF: self})
        return child

root = Tree()
for word in words:
  node = root
  for ch in word:
    node = node[ch]
  node[END] = None
```

Also doesn't give the root a backref, and being a dict, its string representations are far less cluttered than a defaultdict's and thus far more readable:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pp(root)
{'h': {'BACKREF': <Recursion on Tree with id=2494556270320>,
       'i': {'BACKREF': <Recursion on Tree with id=2494556270400>,
             '$': None,
             'y': {'BACKREF': <Recursion on Tree with id=2494556270480>,
                   'a': {'BACKREF': <Recursion on Tree with id=2494556340608>,
                         '$': None}}},
       'e': {'BACKREF': <Recursion on Tree with id=2494556270400>,
             'l': {'BACKREF': <Recursion on Tree with id=2494556340288>,
                   'l': {'BACKREF': <Recursion on Tree with id=2494556340368>,
                         'o': {'BACKREF': <Recursion on Tree with id=2494556340448>,
                               '$': None}}},
             'y': {'BACKREF': <Recursion on Tree with id=2494556340288>,
                   '$': None}}}}
```

The defaultdict result for comparison:

```
>>> pprint.pp(root)
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001A13760BE50>,
            {'BACKREF': None,
             'h': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001A13760BE50>,
                              {'BACKREF': <Recursion on defaultdict with id=1791930855152>,
                               'i': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001A13760BE50>,
                                                {'BACKREF': <Recursion on defaultdict with id=1791930855312>,
                                                 '$': None,
                                                 'y': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001A13760BE50>,
                                                                  {'BACKREF': <Recursion on defaultdict with id=1791930912832>,
                                                                   'a': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001A13760BE50>,
                                                                                    {'BACKREF': <Recursion on defaultdict with id=1791930913232>,
                                                                                     '$': None})})}),
                               'e': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001A13760BE50>,
                                                {'BACKREF': <Recursion on defaultdict with id=1791930855312>,
                                                 'l': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001A13760BE50>,
                                                                  {'BACKREF': <Recursion on defaultdict with id=1791930912912>,
                                                                   'l': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001A13760BE50>,
                                                                                    {'BACKREF': <Recursion on defaultdict with id=1791930912992>,
                                                                                     'o': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001A13760BE50>,
                                                                                                      {'BACKREF': <Recursion on defaultdict with id=1791930913072>,
                                                                                                       '$': None})})}),
                                                 'y': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001A13760BE50>,
                                                                  {'BACKREF': <Recursion on defaultdict with id=1791930912912>,
                                                                   '$': None})})})})
```

Comment: @joseville Like the doc says, that's passed as if it were passed to the dict constructor, i.e., it's used to initialize the *contents* of the new defaultdict.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. I had come up with something similar using a `def` function, but this is more concise. I had trouble understanding how the second argument into `defaultdict` is treated but [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308319/defaultdict-lambda-with-two-arguments-its-not-argument-per-se-for-lack-of-word) helped. Particularly: "We here thus construct a defaultdict with as key-value pairs the items in the 2nd argument, `{BACKREF: node}`, and we use the 1st argument, `tree`, as a "factory" to construct values for missing keys." (quote adapted to fit this example).

Comment: @joseville See the above comments and the answer's update with the second solution.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks for pointing that out! Just to be clear, backreferences don't dynamically point to `node`, they point to whatever the value of `node` was when `defaultdict.__missing__()` was called. So in **Solution 1** above as written, all the backreferences are correct and if I change `node` to `None`, the backreferences won't suddenly all point to `None`. Comment continued...

Comment: But if after the `for` loop (in **Solution 1**) I do: `node = root`, `node['a']['l']['o']['h']['a']`, then the backreferences of `node['a']`, `node['a']['l']`, `node['a']['l']['o']`, `node['a']['l']['o']['h']` and `node['a']['l']['o']['h']['a']` will all point to `node` which equals `root` --  this is the correct backreference for `node['a']`, but not for the others.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you're trying to implement seems easier to write as a class rather than a function.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

class Tree(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, backref=None):
        super().__init__(self.make_child)
        self.backref = backref
    def make_child(self):
        return Tree(backref=self)
```

Usage:

```py
>>> root = Tree()
>>> root['h'].backref is root
True
>>> root['h']['e'].backref is root['h']
True
```

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Good point, that part wasn't really relevant to my answer and I misinterpreted what it was used for in the question.

Comment: Ok, that's what I suspected. But I think there's an optimization making the attribute dicts smaller when we set all attributes in the constructor right away (not sure whether it would have to be in defaultdict's constructor already instead of just yours), so could've been that as well.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks! It works well! I was playing around with this version. Replaced `super().__init__(self.make_child)` with `super().__init__(lambda: Tree(backref=self))` and replaced `self.backref = backref` with `self['backref'] = backref`, but that didn't work and was wondering if you have an idea why? Is it something to do with `self` in the `lambda` maybe not referring to the correct thing at the time the `lambda` is called?

Comment: @joseville Not sure what you did, but that should work, and it does work when I test it. `self` isn't reassigned in the scope it's defined in, so that can't be an issue. Perhaps you were testing like `root['h'].backref is root` instead of `root['h']['backref'] is root`?